# save image to mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

i created this form to add my images to mysql database,and i think i did it right-cause it saves something :D - but it wont show me the image, what should i do to "SEE" the image from mysql?!

this is my form php:

```
$tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if ((($_FILES['file']['type']) == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES['file']['type']) == "image/gif"
|| ($_FILES['file']['type']) == "image/pjpeg"
&& ($_FILES['file']['size']) > 200000) {
$tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
// i also tried addslasheds   
$image = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0) {
    echo "return code : " . $_FILES['FILES']['error'];
}else{
    if (file_exists($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
        echo "your file is already exists!";
    }else{
        Query("INSERT INTO image(image) VALUES ('".$tmp_name."')");
        echo "FILES has been stored";
    }
}
}
}else{
echo "invalid file";
}?>
```

and my code to show the image is:

```
<?php 
require 'lib.php';
$request=Query('SELECT * FROM image');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($request)) {
echo $row['image'];
}?>
```

Comment: Note that mysql_* functions are deprecated. You should use mysqli_ or PDO. As for question have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php I do not see any directory where you are uploading the file. Then you need to echo image tag with proper source

Comment: This is really *your* code? I've seen this a couple of times. You are not storing the image data, but just a temporary filename. Even if you get that back later, the image file will be long gone.

Comment: See also: http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20store%20image%20in%20mysql

Comment: @mario:i wrote it with w3schools help,i wanna to store the image on my database not any directory

Comment: @DeiForm: I saw a database with could save images to it's fields,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting the temporary name into your database won't accomplish anything because it is just that, temporary. You need to save the image somewhere on your server using `move_uploaded_file()` and then save the new *permanent* name to your database so that you can  use it in html image tags later.

```
$filename = "myimage.jpg";
$path = "/var/www/images/".$filename;
$link = "http://domain.com/images/".$filename;
move_uploaded_file($FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path);
$image = mysql_real_escape_string($link);
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0) {
    echo "return code : " . $_FILES['FILES']['error'];
}else{
    Query("INSERT INTO image(image) VALUES ('".$image."')");
    echo "FILES has been stored";
}
```

Then when you retrieve your image:

```
<?php 
require 'lib.php';
$request=Query('SELECT * FROM image');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($request)) {
echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" />";
}?>
```

Comment: images has been successfully moved to the directory, but on retrieve page, i can't see the images!!

Comment: What link is stored in the database and what is your retrieval script printing out?

Comment: my retrieval is image boxes that can't load,

Comment: @user2668542 Can you please provide the HTML for these image boxes that can't load?

Comment: it worked,you had a syntax error which i fixed,
thanks for your help.